# ASP.NET 5: Where are my output DLLs when publishing?

Tags: msbuild, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, dnx, dnu

Where are my output DLLs when publishing an ASP.NET 5 web application?

When running the MSBuild's `FileSystemPublish`, the publish directory looks something like this:

- **approot** folder: packages, runtime and source code
- **wwwroot** folder: web.config and AspNet.Loader.dll
- web
- web.cmd

> MSBuild.exe "C:/MyApplication/MyProj.xproj" /t:Build,FileSystemPublish /p:PublishConfiguration=Release  /p:PublishOutputPathNoTrailingSlash="C:/a/MyApplication"

From the logging output I can see that `dnu publish` is called:

> dnu publish "C:/MyApplication" --out "C:/a/MyApplication" --configuration Release --runtime dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta6 --quiet

If I look inside `web.cmd` I can see that DNX is indeed running the application from source code:

```
@"%~dp0approot\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta6\bin\dnx.exe" --appbase "%~dp0approot\src\MyApplication" Microsoft.Framework.ApplicationHost web %*
```

I am able to point IIS to the wwwroot directory with success.

How does IIS know to call on `web.cmd`? Is this the correct approach to serving up an ASP.NET 5 application in a production environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. IIS doesn't call `web.cmd`. IIS knows how to load `AspNet.Loader` from the `wwwroot` folder.
2. In a production environment you probably don't want to compile from sources because the startup is pretty slow. You should publish precompiled binaries. You do that by passing `--no-source` to `dnu publish`:

`dnu publish "C:/MyApplication" --out "C:/a/MyApplication" --configuration Release --runtime dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta6 --no-source`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Firstly, is it possible to run the application from web.cmd? Secondly, how can I provide `--no-source` through MSBuild?

Comment: web.cmd is for self-hosting primarily on non-iis platforms.

Answer (score 1):

**The question is obsolete**

According to the latest community standup (see [Announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/69)), the HELIOS integration between IIS and asp.net 5 was stopped. Ongoing the only server provided by MS is kestrel. IIS will natively not recognize DNX projects.

You have to start and integrate kestrel into IIS by reverse proxying it using the HttpPlatformHandler (IIS8+).